# I can’t correct responsive big image to mobile screen

Tags: html, css, web, responsive

I create my first web site and I can’t understand how correct responsive my big image in terms flex and overflow hide display for sliding image one by one

This how look my tries to response

```css
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1px; 
}


.doorsSlide{
    width: auto;        
    display: flex;
    height: 430px;
    
    
    
}     
.doorsSlide.large{
    height: 100%;
}
.doorsSlide.small{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please show your relevant HTML in your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I want to help, however I don't have enough information to understand the problem.

Based on the code you entered for `img` that should adjust with different screen resolutions.